# problems with creating tables/rows using pop/push

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table in HTML using javascript. It has an add button that add's new rows and a delete button that removes rows. It looks like this :

[image: Table]

the numbers are the ids

```
    <table id = "table1" border = 2>
        <tr>
            <td> <img id="add" src="images/add_over.png" onclick=help() /> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

---

Basically I'm trying to delete the whole table and recreate it with one row less.

```
var array1 = new Array();

function help() {
    addRow();
    push();
}

function addRow() {
    var tableId= "table1";
    var number= array1.length;
    var newRow = document.getElementById(tableId).insertRow(number+ 1);

    var newData = document.createElement("td");
    var newDiv= document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = array1.length;
    newData.appendChild(newDiv);

    var newCellDeleteButton = document.createElement("td");
    var deleteButtonImg = document.createElement('img');
    deleteButtonImg.id = number;
    deleteButtonImg.border = '0';
    deleteButtonImg.src = "images/delete_up.png";
    deleteButtonImg.onmouseover = function() {
        this.src = 'images/delete_over.png';
    };
    deleteButtonImg.onmouseout = function() {
        this.src = 'images/delete_up.png';
    };
    deleteButtonImg.onclick = function() {
        deleteRow(number);
    };
    newCellDeleteButton.appendChild(deleteButtonImg);
    newRow.appendChild(newRow);
    newRow.appendChild(newCellDeleteButton);
}


function deleteRow(rowID) {
    var tempHelpRow = array1.length;
    pop(rowID);

    for (var i = 1; i <= tempHelpRow ; i++) {
        document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(1);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
        addRow();
    }

}

function pop(ID) {

    array1.pop(ID);
}

function push() {

    var test = new objectt();
    array1.push(test);
}

function objectt() {

}
```

the problem is, that if i try to delete one row it deletes everything.

Comment: if it works with Windows Gadgets, yes.

Comment: Thanks! Using jQuery right away would've been too easy.. I feel like an idiot now!

Comment: Adding new rows and editing values works like a charm, unless I'm trying to combine both. I'm also having trouble to understand how jEditable works (http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html)

Still reading the documentation.

Comment: Possible to show your code in some [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cJ63X/

It's pretty much what I got from the examples

I read that the first parameter of editable is where the data will be saved to - how does that work?

Comment: actually the fiddle is not working. upon clicking the add row, nothing is happening.. yeah, that is the way you have to show a fiddle! :)

Comment: We found another example which worked for us. Thanks for your help!